# Android Youtube like video player running across activities

Tags: android

I need to implement a youtube like behavior video player. If user clicks back while on the player activity and video is playing, the desired behavior is:

1. kill current activity
2. show a mini floating player on the previous activity
3. seamlessly continue playing from same position on the floating player.

This can be achieved with passing the position while moving from one screen to another, but the player will have load from scratch and lose all the buffered (cached) data.

What are the common patterns to achieve this continuous playing of a video? (keeping a static instance of the player? launch a service that hold the player?)

Comment: Why do you want a new `Activity` for the player? You can inflate a view in the same `Activity`. Make the view full screen and move the view on drag to bottom of the screen and scale/resize. The player won't start anew and will continue seamlessly.

Comment: @Abbas when going from small player to fullscreen this is kinda what I do. But i need a mini player at the bottom across all activities of the app.

Comment: you may use the fragments instead of activities, and pass the player view between them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I am adding a feature to an existing app that uses activities

Comment: Share Player instance and unbind the player from View when any activity (that supports the player) goes in `onPause()` and rebind to the same view when in `onResume()`. So you'll be sharing player instance between `Activities` which may or may not result in an invalid context exception. `MediaPlayer` doesn't require context but other players might. You might be able to overcome that by providing application's context instead.

Comment: @Abbas This is sort of my question. how would you share an instance between activities?

Comment: Really depends on the Architecture and design patterns you based your apps on. However a singleton design *should* work for all.

Comment: Or you can move the player into your `Applicaiton` which should provide you with necessary life cycle events to handle the player.